# Automate filling cells in multiples based on another cell when comparing two columns

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a screenshot of the tables below. What I am trying to get automated in google sheets is a cost comparison based on uses. Whenever the price from the small table gets transposed to the big table on the left they should increase based on the expected uses. For example Option A increases equal to its price every time it is used 3 times. I have filled in the cost in the left table to show how it should look, but I want a formula that will auto populate the left table after inputting values in the small table to the right.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. I ended up using an IFS formula.

=IFS(A4=$F$4,(ROUNDUP(A4/$F$4,0))*$G$4)

The IFS formula allows multiple nested if thens. Basically, this reads if the uses is less than uses in the small table then return the price, but if it is greater than or equal to the uses then divide the two and round up to determine the multiple of the uses and multiply by the price.